Linear transformation and Lebesgue measure
Question
Suppose $A\in M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ is a row addition matrix as defined in this Wikipedia page (in some book, also called Type 3 matrix), i.e., $A$ has the form
\begin{align*}
A_{i,j}\triangleq \begin{cases}
  1& \text{ if $i=j$ }\\
  c& \text{ if $(i,j)=(a,b)$ }\\
  0& \text{ if otherwise }
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
where $c$ is a non-zreo real constant and $(a,b)$ is some element of $ \{1,\dots ,n\}^2$ such that $a\neq b$.
Show that for each Lebesgue measurable set $E$
in $\mathbb{R}^n$, its image $A(E)$ is also Lebesgue measurable and
\begin{align}
|A(E)|=|E|
\end{align}

Context and Attempt
I was attempting to show that for all $T\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$, we have $|T(E)|=|\operatorname{det}(T)| \cdot |E|$, and I was informed by the Internet that the proof lies in decomposing $T$ into product of elementary matrices, which make perfect sense to me. Although it make sense, I have a hard time proving the case for the row addition matrix and when I looked up books like Zygmund, they never give a detailed proof on this proposition. Thanks in advance for help in all forms.
——————
Searching Status: this post asked only about the measurability of $T(E)$ and received great answer, but did not received a proof for $|T(E)|=|\operatorname{det}(T)|\cdot |E|$

Why not use the outer measure for Lebesgue measure?  In that case, the area formulas for cuboids are immediate (a linear algebra fact).

@MichaelBurr, thanks for your reply, but I failed to see how the area formula is an immediate consequence of the definition of Lebesgue outer measure.
